# Creating a comments voting system

Tags: plugins, jquery, comments

I am trying to put together a voting system for comments and I can't figure out how to make the jQuery function to work. 
Here is the php function that updates the comment meta with the new vote count and with the users ids (I think this function is correct) :

```
function commentsvote_ajaxhandler() {
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], "commentsvote_nonce")) {
      exit("Something Wrong");
    }  
    $results = '';
    global $wpdb;
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $commentid = $_POST['commentid'];
        $votecount = get_comment_meta($commentid, '_commentsvote', true) != '' ? get_comment_meta($commentid, '_commentsvote', true) : '0';
        $votecountNew = $votecount + 1;
        update_comment_meta($commentid, '_commentsvote', $votecountNew);

        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
        $voters = get_comment_meta($commentid, '_commentsvoters', true);
        if ($voters == '') {
            update_comment_meta($commentid, '_commentsvoters', $user_ID);
        } else {
            $voters_IDs = $voters.','.$user_ID;
            update_comment_meta($commentid, '_commentsvoters', $voters_IDs);        
    }       
    $results.='<div class="votescore" ><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" disabled="disabled"></a> Voted.</div>';
    }
    die($results);
    }
```

And this is my jQuery function which adds the vote count but it doesn't adds the user id in the comment's meta:

```
function commentsvote_add(comment_id,nonce) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: votecommentajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'commentsvote_ajaxhandler',
        commentid: comment_id,
        nonce: nonce
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        var linkofcomment = '#commentsvote-' + comment_id;
        jQuery(linkofcomment).html('');
        jQuery(linkofcomment).append(data);
    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

How can I modify this jQuery function to add the user ids in the comment meta "_commentsvoters" when the vote button is pressed?

Comment: The same way you passed the other data-- the `action`, `commentid`, and `nonce`. What is the difficulty?

Comment: The call to add your function to the necessary hook is missing, can you add it to your question? Also can you indent your code so it's easier to read?

Comment: It seems that the code is correct, I didn't declare the variable "$commentid". All works perfect now.